# Adding a Snagit image to the body of an e-mail

Tags: gmail

My company just moved to Gmail and I am having trouble finding a way to add a Snagit image to the body of my e-mail.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, pasting images into the body of an email (not as an attachment) does not work. Gmail team is working on it, and hopefully solve it soon. However, there is a workaround to try. The following is the [explanation](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=29538497df5404a1&hl=en&fid=29538497df5404a10004979f9c4244c0&hltp=2) of Paul McDonalds (Gmail Product Manager) about the issue dated Dec 18th, 2010:

> Copy and paste works everywhere, it
>   should work in Gmail too, right? We
>   agree and we are working on a way to
>   enable those of you with modern
>   browsers (Google Chrome is our
>   favorite) to copy and paste an image
>   from the clipboard into the email
>   body. The problem is that most browser
>   don't allow you to do this without a
>   bunch of work-arounds. We aren't quite
>   there yet but trust that its something
>   we are working on
>
> In the meantime you can use the
>   "insert image" lab that adds a new
>   button to the rich text compose
>   menu.By clicking this button you can
>   insert an image directly into the body
>   of the email and it will be displayed
>   inline when read.